# What are the choices in the people and groups column based on?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, user

I'm using SharePoint Online modern experience.

I have People and groups column in my SPO list, and "Choose from" was set to "All Users".
Then I wonder what are the choices in that column.
Tenant based? Organizations based? or the others?
I would like to know where the choices in this column are being obtained from.

I would appreciate any idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With Person or Group column in SharePoint online, Users can select people or groups from the site’s membership source (for example, Active Directory) and associate them with items in a list.

Answer (score 0):

In the Person Or Group column, you have the choices to search either all the users in your tenant or the users from the specific SharePoint Group.

[image]

If you select the option SharePoint Group, then it restricts the search to the specified SharePoint group only. It will show the suggestions of users who are part of the selected SharePoint Group. This comes handy when we have limited target audience which will be involved and we don't want users to randomly add anyone from the tenant in the column.

However, there is a caveat with this choice, like if you have added the Office 365 Group added into your SharePoint Group, then it does not search from that O365 Group.

[SharePoint O365: People or Group Column](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/sharepoint-o365-people-or-group-column/m-p/299241)